# Detect UILabel text change in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to get notified when there is a change in a `UILabel`'s text or would I be better off using a `UITextField` with `userInteractionEnabled` set to `false` and using its `UIControlEditingChanged` event to fulfil my purpose?

For ex. I need to run certain lines of code every time I change the `UILabel`'s text and accordingly. So instead of writing those 100 lines of almost similar code for every case I change the `UILabel`'s text, I wish to write it together in one place and call it every time the `UILabel` is changed. I don't even know if that makes any sense. Forgive me but I cannot expose much of the code.

Comment: Why do you need this? You are explicitly calling `someLabel.text = ...`. So you already know it's being changed.

Comment: Hmm.. to cut a few lines of code let's just say

Comment: You need to update your question with the code you have and what you want to be different. Otherwise this isn't very clear.

Comment: Ok.. Can't really expose much of the code.. I'll see what I can do

Comment: But why don't you just call a function, each time you change the text?

Comment: Did you try nsnotificationcenter.defaultcenter.addobserver()?

Comment: @Christian I am randomising the text of the UILabel and I need to update certain UI elements according to the new value of the UILabel.

Comment: @IamMashed I haven't

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create a class that inherits from UILabel. Such as:

```
class YourLabel: UILabel {

    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            if let text = text {
                println("Text changed.")
            } else {
                println("Text not changed.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create a outlet of this class for your object.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: YourLabel!
label.text = "abc"
```

Comment: Updated my answer. You can check it.

Answer (score 31):

### Swift 3

First, add an observer to UILabel for key path `text`.

```
label.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
```

Then

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
  if keyPath == "text" {
    print("old:", change?[.oldKey])
    print("new:", change?[.newKey])
  }
}
```

### Swift 2

```
label.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: [.Old, .New], context: nil)
```

Then

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "text" {
        print("old:", change["old"])
        print("new:", change["new"])
    }
}
```

### Console Output

For example console would be:

```
old: Optional(<null>)
new: Optional(ABC)
```

Comment: This does work. I have used it over the other answer because a function can then be called from the same class in which the label is used.

Comment: WTH is this?  atreat's answer is a basic in software and it, you know, works :)

Comment: @Fattie this is KVO (Key-Value Observing), which is what is being used by didSet. KVO has been since Objective-C and can allow for finer control.

Comment: For sure - I was just teasing, since the latest Swift syntax is much more up to date!  :)

Comment: Should be the correct answer. Instead of subclassing UILabel just to observe changes in 'didSet' in my opinion this is the correct way.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this simply with a subclass of UILabel:

```
class Label : UILabel {
    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            print("Text changed from \(oldValue) to \(text)")
        }
    }
}
```

`oldValue` is a special value provided by Swift. 
See [Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262)

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3.2 and later, the preferred method is to use a closure-based observer:

```
@IBOutlet public weak var label: UILabel!

var textObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

func someAppropriateFunction() {
  ...
  textObserver = label.observe(\.text) { [weak self] (label, observedChange) in
    self?.updateStuff()
  }
}
```

The closure will pass you the label instance and an [NSKeyValueObservedChange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyvalueobservedchange) that includes the following properties:

```
  indexes: IndexSet?
  isPrior: Bool
  kind: NSKeyValueObservedChange<Value>.Kind
  newValue: Value?
  oldValue: Value?
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

If you want to observe text changes in the label and make an animation. You need to create subclass UILabel

```
class ObservedLabelAnimate: SpringLabel {

    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            if let text = text {
                if oldValue != text {
                    animation = "fadeInLeft"
                    duration = 1.2
                    animate()
                }
                print("This is oldvalue \(oldValue), and this is the new one \(text)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for this example, I subclass 'SpringLabel' that inherits from UILabel

from https://github.com/MengTo/Spring

Basically it will check if the oldValue and text (new one) is different then the animation will be fired

To use:

@IBOutlet weak var label: ObservedLabelAnimate!