# How can a UIButton listen to changes to other Buttons, a change to a UILabel's text, and a change to a UITextView all at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uilabel

My vc contains:

-1 name textView

-1 label // for flavors

-2 radio buttons // yes and no

-1 nextButton

What I want to do is keep the nextButton disabled until the textView is filled out, the label's text value is changed from its initial title of "Pick a Flavor" to whatever flavor they pick, and 1 of the radio buttons are selected.

I know using a textView's `textViewDidEndEditing()` I can listen to changes on it after the user finishes editing disable or enable the nextButton.

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    handleTextInputChanged()
}

@objc func handleTextInputChanged() {
    let isFormValid = nameTextView.text?.count ?? 0 > 0

    if isFormValid {
        nextButton.isEnabled = true
        nextButton.backgroundColor = .red
    } else {
        nextButton.isEnabled = false
        nextButton.backgroundColor = .lightgray
    }
}
```

**How would I additionally disable or enable the nextButton based on wether or not one of the radio buttons were selected and the label's text is changed in addition to checking the nameTextView has text inside of it?**

FYI the label's text is initially set with "Pick a Flavor". I have a gesture recognizer hooked up to it and when its tapped a new vc with a tableView is presented. The user picks a flavor, a protocol sends it back to this vc and the label's text will change to whatever flavor was selected (eg the label's title would say "Butter Pecan" if chosen). The nextButton should be disabled as long as the label's title is still set to "Pick a Flavor".

code:

```
let flavorLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Pick a Flavor"
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return label
}()

let nameTextView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    return textView
}()

let noButton: DLRadioButton = {
    let button = DLRadioButton(type: .custom)
    button.setTitle("No", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(noButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

let yesButton: DLRadioButton = {
    let button = DLRadioButton(type: .custom)
    button.setTitle("Yes", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yesButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

let nextButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.isEnabled = false
    button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

var choice: Bool?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    flavorVC.delegate = self
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    handleTextInputChanged()
}

@objc func handleTextInputChanged() {
    let isFormValid = nameTextView.text?.count ?? 0 > 0

    if isFormValid {
        nextButton.isEnabled = true
        nextButton.backgroundColor = .red
    } else {
        nextButton.isEnabled = false
        nextButton.backgroundColor = .lightgray
    }
}

@objc fileprivate func noButtonPressed() {
    choice = false
}

@objc fileprivate func yesButtonPressed() {
    choice = true
}

// delegate method from FlavorController
func selectedFlavor(flavor: String) {

    flavorLabel.text = flavor // eg. "Butter Pecan"
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to use Reactive Programming, e.g RxSwift which is best for event changes. If you want more advance, then you can use this library: https://github.com/duyduong/DDMvvm which is a MVVM pattern library using RxSwift for data binding. There is an example how you can bind your properties and listen to changes to update view state exactly what you need

Comment: @dduyduong why not use kvo instead of an observer? I used kvo on the label and it works fine. I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32571505/4833705

Comment: Yes, you can use KVO, that's good too. But if you want a solid framework that can help you to ground up, more extendable and easy on Unit Test, then give my suggestion a try. To be honest, I wrote that library. It is based on my years experience working on MVVM and applied it to private projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function that check all like this

```
func checkAll() {
    nextButto.isEnabled = flavorLabel.text != "Pick a Flavor" &&
    nameTextField.text != "" &&
    (noButton.someProerty != || yesButton.someProerty != )
}
```

and call it from textfield and button targets plus

```
var ob:NSKeyValueObservation?

ob = flavorLabel.observe(\.text,options:[.new], changeHandler: { [unowned self] _, change in

   self.checkAll()
}
```

I left the radio checks because both of them are custom , so you should know what to check , btw you can set tag of selected to 1 inside the target method and check according to it or some other logic you want

Comment: sorry for getting back to you so late. I tried it but it didn't work. 1 mistake was mines as the name textField is actually a textView but I added the checkAll to the nextButton target with .touchUpInside and added the KVO to the label as you did but it didn't work. I was rushing to go do something when I first put up the question and I was thinking about a textField instead of a textVIew. I reworded the question and updated the code. Sorry about that

Comment: I figured it out using a part of your answer and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32571505/4833705 . I'm not sure why yours didn't work though once I made the adjustments? Since you lead me in the right direction and I asked the wrong question if you want to update your answer I'll accept it. I'm not going to post an answer because you had the correct one but answered it based on the wrong question. I'll wait for you.

Comment: the other part of answer is old to addObserver , but this is inline block instead of attaching a function

Comment: btw put  the lbl observe code inside viewDidLoad 
, see edit

Comment: I did put it in viewdidload, I never used the new way before but I remember reading about it in an entirely different question. When I tried it the new way, I put a break point on it and after I selected the flavor it never hit the break point but it did with the old way. I’ll try again later

Comment: @LanceSamaria you can also try **[.change]** option

Comment: I’ll try it in about 2 hours and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: I forgot to ask, you said add the checkAll function as a target on the nextButton, should I use .touchDownInside for that?

Comment: it's **touchUpInside** for any action , but here nextButton target method should process it's function such as go to another VC or anything else , set checkAll as target    for any no,yes button , editingChanged of textfield and label observe as above

Comment: sorry for the late upvote. You answered it correctly when I was using a textField and I changed it to a textView afterwards. I used the same logic for the textView and it worked. Thanks for the help. Cheers!